# Read images and displaying(Outputting) from HDFS using Hadoop MapReduce

Tags: java, image, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I  haved only played accross text files in hadoop. I would like to experiment on images too.

How can I read an image and display(output) images?

When I googled,the stackoverflow itself gave me an idea that

We need to convert images to sequence file and then this file is taken as the input to MapReduce job. Is it like that. So in 2 nd MapReduce job how can we out it as images?

And we will not get the exact single image in our map(if the image size is large), Do we need to go with WholeFileInputFormat?

What I did so far is

1. Copied images into HDFS
2. Wrote a MapReduce job to convert images to sequence file .

Please Advice.

Can any one help me with examples.

Comment: May be you want to take a look this library: [HIPI](http://hipi.cs.virginia.edu/index.html)

Comment: @Ashrith: Thought like will do it in Mapreduce and later move on to HIPI for optimizing. Is there any example code available?